# How to integrate paytm gateway in asp.net web application

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am trying to integrate Paytm in an ASP.NET website. Payment processing is going well, but when a transaction is completed, it redirects to my "callbackurl" page.

Here I don`t know **how to read the response of the transaction**. I checked my callback page using inspect element but there was no json or any error message or message in console.

Answer (score 0):

You can call this function during your page load event of callback url. If checksumhash is matched then you can call additional parameters.

```
String merchantKey = "****************"; // Replace the with the Merchant Key provided by Paytm at the time of registration.

Dictionary<string, string> parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        string paytmChecksum = "";
        foreach (string key in Request.Form.Keys)
        {
            parameters.Add(key.Trim(), Request.Form[key].Trim());
        }

        if (parameters.ContainsKey("CHECKSUMHASH"))
        {
            paytmChecksum = parameters["CHECKSUMHASH"];
            parameters.Remove("CHECKSUMHASH");
        }

        if (CheckSum.verifyCheckSum(merchantKey, parameters, paytmChecksum))
        {
            lbl_status.Text = parameters["STATUS"];
            Response.Write("Checksum Matched");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Checksum MisMatch");
        }
```